# Excel Formatting Numbers in Cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formatting

I have a column of data in Excel;

```
07902555018   
07902556019   
07902557020   
07902558021   
07902559022   
...
```

The values change but the placement of three zeros is constant. I am trying to remove the First Zero, Second Zero and the Zero in the 3rd to last position.

```
792555518   
792555619  
792555720
...
```

After the values are changed I am trying to add two hyphens

```
79-25555-18  
79-25556-19  
19-25557-20
```

I tried using: `=TEXT(--SUBSTITUTE(--E2,"0","",2),"00-00000-00")`
However a problem occurs:

`079020638020` becomes `792-06380-20`
However `79-20638-20` is the value I want returned in instances like these.

Comment: Could it be that your cell is formated as number ? Which means the leading 0 get ignored. Format it as text with the leading 0 and it should work

Comment: I apologize i put an extra zero in the command and gave the wrong value in the Original post. 00-00000-00 is the format desired. I've checked the cell formatting and it is definitely Text, not number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only know that the placement of the zeros is constant then use `REPLACE` rather than `SUBSTITUTE`. This replaces (removes) the 1st, 4th and 9th zeros:

```
=TEXT(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(A1,1,1,""),3,1,""),8,1,""),"00-00000-00")
```

Comment: @Callum-Thank you so much that actually solved the issue. I am new to excel and learning the commands. This may be asking a little much but I notice you have three nested Replace commands. What would occur if for instance in this command if a zero was omitted from that placement.

Comment: Hi Neil, glad it helped. I don't exactly understand what you mean but the formula blindly replaces the 1/4/9 characters. If it was applied to a different string (e.g. no zero at the beginning) it would still replace those characters, whether they were zeros or not. Does that answer your question?

Comment: Yes that does answer the question. That was exactly what I was trying to understand if it was replacing the 1st,4th and 9th character or looking for the actual zero. This still solves my issue because I generally have those zeros in those place always, if not I can add that.

Comment: I noticed it's actually the 10th you're excluding (the initial example is a bit misleading). Anyway, you can use this (if you want) to check if you have zeros in the right positions: `=(MID(A1,1,1)+MID(A1,4,1)+MID(A1,10,1))=0`

Comment: Its returns true for each. I suppose how you wrote the intial formula doesnt seem to change the outcome as its still correctly displaying for some 800+ records I ran it against. Works exactly as I needed and accomplishes what took me 3 columns to do using Replace, Concat and Substitute.

Answer (score 0):

Probably:

`079020638020` (Cell E2) is formatted as number. 
Which means its actually: `79020638020`

Your formula removes the second occurence:
7902**0**638020

So you have 2 possibilities to get it working, either format the cell as text (So the leading 0 will not get deleted) or change the formula to:

```
=TEXT(--SUBSTITUTE(--E2,"0","", 1),"00-000000-00")
```

Result would be: `79-206380-20`

Comment: I apologize i put an extra zero in the command and gave the wrong value in the Original post. 00-00000-00 is the format desired.

I've checked the cell formatting and it is definitely Text, not number